# PowerDNS Scripting - Getting the DNS Query's Unique ID

Tags: lua, dns, powerdns

I'm writing lua scripts for PowerDNS.

I wish to get some kind of a unique ID for each DNS query when my script intercepts a DNS query.

I'm intercepting the DNS queries with the "**preresolve**" and "**postresolve**" functions and they don't have any unique ID that will symbolize the current DNS query it's handling.

I saw that when using the function "**ipfilter**", I can use the GetID() function to get the DNS query ID. 
This ability is missing in the "preresolve" and "postresolve" functions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this is not possible. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is another way

Comment: I need it mainly for statistics and logs.
I want to time the delay my functions implementation adds to the query flow.
I also wish to have the ability to follow a specific query through the logs.

Comment: Without having it tested, it might be possible to set an ID in the dq-object in the preresolve-hook and read it from the postresolve-hook: `dq.myId = "1234"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading from PDNS Recursor version 3.0 to 4.0 I found my answer.

In version 4, 'preresolve' and 'postresolve' functions get the dq (DNSQuestion) object,
the dq object contains two fields that can help with the query ID.

One, you can use the original query ID by getting the value from

```
dq:getDH():getID()
```

Two, dq can contain a custom LUA object reference that is persistent throughout the lifetime of the dq object.

```
local data={}
data["domaindetails"]= dq.udpAnswer
dq.data=data
```

Find more details in their Scripting manual:
https://doc.powerdns.com/md/recursor/scripting/#the-dnsquestion-dq-object